# PEM_read_X509 function

Tags: encryption, openssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

Can `PEM_read_X509` function read in a CA cert file with private key properly? is it intelligent enough to handle the private key section? Or it will error out if the `.pem` file contains the private key?

Comment: I'll not answer, but I'm pretty sure that the `X509` return value is just the certificate in OpenSSL. A certificate and private key are two separate things in this API (which is, in my opinion, the correct way to look at it).  However, I don't know how an additional private key is handled; with a bit of luck it is simply skipped....

Comment: BTW I think the question is OK, but heck, I would just have *tried* myself.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR: YES**

Almost all OpenSSL `PEM_read[_bio]_XYZ` functions will accept a file (or equivalent) containing other data before and/or after the PEM block of type XYZ, and ignore the other data as long as it's not on the same line(s). This is designed to allow 'comments' that describe the PEM data, but also works for *other* types of PEM data or just arbitrary data not related to the PEM data at all. In particular `PEM_read_X509` will read the first block of type CERTIFICATE, X509 CERTIFICATE, or TRUSTED CERTIFICATE and ignore anything and everything else, including a private key block.

Similarly `PEM_read_[algo_or_PKCS8]PrivateKey` will read the first block of type [ENCRYPTED|RSA|DSA|EC] PRIVATE KEY and ignore everything else, but fail if you tried to read a specific algorithm and the (first) private key block found was a different type. (It also fails, of course, if a valid block is found but is encrypted by a password and you don't provide the correct password either as an argument or via a callback. And if no valid block is found.)

I'm not sure if by 'CA cert' you mean a cert *for* a CA, or a cert *issued by* a CA and *for* an end-entity like your webserver or mailbox. Except for a personal/local or test CA you or a colleague or your organization set up, most ordinary users should have the certs for one or more CAs but never their privatekeys. And if someone responsible for a real CA like say LetsEncrypt was asking such basic questions on Stackoverflow I would be greatly alarmed and worried over the competence and thus security of that CA.